# Finding the SubPartition Key Column and List values in Oracle Table

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

I am not a DBA but a developer , I need to work with an existing table which has `PARTITIONING_TYPE` RANGE and `SUBPARTITIONING_TYPE` LIST. I can see the Partition Key Column as given below from the `ALL_PART_KEY_COLUMNS` table.

[image]

How Can I know what is SubPartition Key Column and its pre-defined list ? Kindly help if you happen to know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join three dictionary views of `user_` prefixed type instead of `all_` in order to be able to query from an ordinary user such as

```
SELECT s1.column_name AS "Key Column", s2.subpartition_name AS "Subpartition Names"
  FROM user_subpart_key_columns s1 
  JOIN user_part_key_columns p
    ON s1.name = p.name
  JOIN user_tab_subpartitions s2
    ON s2.table_name = p.name  
 WHERE s1.name = 'YOUR_TABLE'   
 ORDER BY s2.subpartition_position
```

Comment: Thank you, I am reading the tables using a RO user , not with the User who is the Owner, Could that be a problem ?

Comment: Hi @DivyaMV . Yes, that will be problem unless `user_` prefixes are replaced with `all_` for those three dictionary views while enquering from a different user.

Comment: thanks again, it helps. I want to understand a bit more ,When the SubPartition is a LIST, shouldn't we be providing the static LIST of allowed values in the template while defining the SubPartition ? I see all kinds of subpartitionNames in the output..I thought there will be a list of values defined explicitly .. if this is correct, Where can i find the exact template for SubPartition.. ?

Comment: My problem as a developer is , I think I am inserting a NOT allowed value for the SubPartionKey Column. I want to get to the rootcause of it.

Comment: You're welcome @DivyaMV . Whether the subparition is of type LIST or RANGE, you can display those defined static values by adding `s2.high_value` to the current query.

Comment: Could you please help me with a less relared query here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67735655/can-one-insert-operation-prevent-another-concurrent-ddl....