# Oracle Lock , How do they differ?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, locking, database-locking

What is the difference between the below two erros.as far as i understood, they happen in case of a Lock. But do you know the differene in scenarios where one might occure.

`ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object`
and
`ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified`

Answer (score 0):

Example for `ORA-04021` might be this: there's a package in your schema. It contains a procedure which does some job that takes 15 minutes to finish. Someone runs that procedure. Meanwhile, you'd want to *fix* something in that package, so you edit its code and want to compile it. Well, you can't - it is being used so you'll have to wait until it is released. Oracle tells you that *timeout occurred while you're waiting to lock the package and compile it*.

Example for `ORA-00054`: there's a table. You update some values in it, but didn't commit (nor rollback) as you have to do *something else* as well. In another session, another user wants to alter one of table's columns (for example, enlarge its size). ALTER will then raise 0RA-00054 which says that table is *busy* (you're updating it in another session, right?) so you'll have to wait until transaction commits (or rollbacks).

Comment: Thank you, that does throw some light.. I have a problem with ORA-04021 from a procedure, could you please help me understand why it happens without a manual compilation attempt ? the question is here https://stackoverflow.com/q/67735655/4260544